# Suggestion for Self learning

Tags: feature-request

I was banned from asking Questions in mathematics , may be because I ask Questions that seem too broad , but I'd like to mention the reason and suggest a solution and I hope people will react positively here.

The problem that my study of mathematics was from engineering perspective,
I use mathematics as a tool, and my questions was toward a self study of pure mathematics because I always wanted to know how mathematics is built up from Logic and foundations up to analysis passing by structure and space (that order according to Wikipedia page) .

I know that my question seemed to much broad and unimportant for the professionals here , but my suggestion is that if the community make a
forum or division specifically for those beginners who want to learn mathematics in a rigorous way and receive advice and help also may be short tutorials not to teach but to provide people with correct prerequisites and how the subject is divided and well known text books for each category ..

PLEASE keep in mind that not all people who can access that forum can get such help due to low quality education in their countries ...

such a suggestion could help people like me ...

I hope people react positively toward my suggestion and thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you deleted questions which were poorly received? Because looking at only the questions you have on your profile, I'm quite surprised you're banned. Also, I'd recommend using the math chat forums here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com. Usually there will be a couple of good Samaritans willing to answer and help explain concepts on an informal basis.

Comment: it have been long time since I last visited the site REALLY I don't remember whether i deleted or not but What I remember is that For some Questions may be in computer science also I asked questions about prerequisites and things like that .. may be that's the reason ... I tried asking a question today but I found that I am banned in this forum ...again am not sure If I deleted any thing in that forum ...

Answer (score 5):

> receive advice and help also may be short tutorials not to teach but to provide people with correct prerequisites and how the subject is divided

Trying to do this in general for every subject would be a highly subjective and time-consuming task that doesn't fit our format, as such. We're just focused on helping people solve questions at hand, I think. Now, it's possible to formulate individual questions to attain that end, and I think we already handle stuff like that. It seems like what is being requested is a departure from that, otherwise.

> and well known text books for each category .

We have plenty of posts that do this, you just have to search for them.

Comment: thanks for your answer .. you made things clear ... I'll try searching google and asking specific questions here .. :)